# Expanding/Shrinking a Div using JQuery and CSS

Tags: jquery, css, html, expand

I am trying to use JQuery and CSS to allow users to navigate through a "wall" of different size images.

Basically, when a user hovers the mouse over an image, I want it to expand (which is currently working) and I would like the div to increase in width too, to show some additional information.  For some reason, when I hover at this point, there is some really funky behavior, and when I mouseout, the image closes completely.  I have a feeling I'm missing a "stop" in there somewhere, but I can't figure out where.  Can someone take a look?

JQuery:

```
jQuery(function($){
                $('.bar').mosaic({
                    animation   :   'slide'
                });
            });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="MBT-CSS3">
        <!--Bar-->
        <div class="mosaic-block bar">
            <a href="http://buildinternet.com/project/mosaic" target="_blank" class="mosaic-overlay">

                    <h4>This video is really cool!  Click to watch more!</h4>
                    <p>by Media Innovation Team</p>

            </a>


            <!-- <img src="http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/mosaic/mosaic.jpg"/> -->
            <img src="img/grad1.png"/>

        </div>
  </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
```

CSS

```
.MBT-CSS3 div{
-webkit-transform:scale(0.7); /*Webkit 0.7 times the original Image size*/
-moz-transform:scale(0.7); /*Mozilla 0.7 times the original Image size*/
-o-transform:scale(0.7); /*Opera 0.7 times the original Image size*/
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s; /*Webkit: Animation duration*/
-moz-transition-duration: 0.5s; /*Mozilla Animation duration*/
-o-transition-duration: 0.5s; /*Opera Animation duration*/
/*opacity: 0.5;
z-index: 1;*/
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
background-color:#000;
width: auto;
height: auto;
/*margin: 0 10px 5px 0; */
}
.MBT-CSS3 div:hover{
-webkit-transform:scale(1.1); /*Webkit: 0.5 times the original Image size*/
-moz-transform:scale(1.1); /*Mozilla 0.5 times the original Image size*/
-o-transform:scale(1.1); /*Opera 0.5 times the original Image size*/
/*box-shadow:0px 0px 30px gray;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 30px gray;
-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 30px gray; */
opacity: 1;
z-index: 100;
width:600px;
/*height:250px; */  
}
```

Thanks to anyone that might be able to help!!!!  I really appreciate your time!

Comment: You are using a jQuery plugin?  You might want to mention that in your question.  Also, posting a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) example might get you more assistance.

Comment: Wow that is indeed funky... I put it in jsfiddle to play around with. http://jsfiddle.net/dlikhten/QqFrj/1/

Comment: Just a fyi, JSFiddle posted by Dmitriy is not working too good in Safari.  "Funky" to say the least... it's jumping all around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
                $(document).ready(function(){
          var busy = 0;
          $('.MBT-CSS3').mouseover(function(){
              if(!busy)
                  {
                      busy = 1;                      
                    $('#img').animate({
                   '-webkit-transform':'scale(1.1)',
                    '-moz-transform':'scale(1.1)',
                    '-o-transform':'scale(1.1)',
                    'opacity': '1',
                    'z-index': '100',
                    'width' : '600'
                  }, function(){busy = 0;});
                  }
          });
          $('.MBT-CSS3').mouseout(function(){
          if(!busy)
              {
                  busy = 1;                      
                    $('#img').animate({
                   '-webkit-transform':'scale(.7)',
                    '-moz-transform':'scale(.7)',
                    '-o-transform':'scale(.7)',
                    'opacity': '0.5',
                    'z-index': '1',
                    'width' : '300'
                  }, function(){busy = 0;});
              }
          });
      });
```

Should work.I did add a `id="img"` to the image you used. Hope this helps! You can add/remove/edit any of the attributes as you like.
Removed the whole `.MBT-CSS3 :hover` part of your CSS as well.
Edited for the whole `'MBT-CSS3'` class, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is the `:hover`. What happens is that the animation plays and you are no longer hovering over the element due to new dimentions/position. Thus hover is removed and the cycle repeats.

Answer (score 0):

THanks so much for the help.  I actually got it working by just setting the specific width and height of the initial div.

So whereas I did have:

```
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
background-color:#000;
width: auto;
height: auto;
/*margin: 0 10px 5px 0; */
}
```

I changed it to:

```
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
background-color:#000;
width: 350;
height: 250;
/*margin: 0 10px 5px 0; */
}
```

and it worked great.  I really appreciate all of your time and help with this!  You guys are awesome!